# Images not displaying in Javascript

Tags: javascript

i did this code following my lecturer's code. When you click the button an image is supposed to come with a text. Also the when the mouse hovers over the button they change color (This part works fine).
The text also appears. But the image doesn't. In the lecturer's code it works fine. Can someone help me ? :)

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="java.css">
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function haha() {
      let i = document.getElementById("img");
      let url = "haha.jpg";
      i.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`;
      document.getElementById("facetext").innerHTML = "This is my haha face";
    }

    function happy() {
      let i = document.getElementById("img");
      let url = "happy.png";

      i.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`;
      document.getElementById("facetext").innerHTML = "This is my happy face";
    }

    function angry() {
      let i = document.getElementById("img");
      let url = "angry.jpg";

      i.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`;
      document.getElementById("facetext").innerHTML = "This is my angry face";
    }

    function changebg(color) {
      color.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }

    function defaultbg(color) {
      color.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script></script>
  
  <div class="inner">
    <button onclick="haha()" id="btn" onmouseover="changebg(this)" onmouseout="defaultbg(this)">  Happy Face</button> <br><br>
    <button onclick="angry()" id="btn" onmouseover="changebg(this)" onmouseout="defaultbg(this)">Angry Face</button><br><br>
    <button onclick="happy()" id="btn" onmouseover="changebg(this)" onmouseout="defaultbg(this)"> Haha Face </button><br><br>

    <div id="img"></div>
    <p id="facetext"></p>
  </div>

  <script src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are your images? How to you run your webpage? Which webserver do you use?

Comment: Are the paths to the images correct?

Comment: Your JS is working, the image URL is set as a background, and `angry.jpg` will work fine if it's in the same directory as the HTML page. You might just need to set a `height` in CSS for that `#img` div (without any CSS, its height is `0px`)

Comment: @blex This should be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like it works fine, if the images are indeed in the same directory as the HTML page.

However, if the div `#img` does not have any styling, its height is `0px`. You might just need to set a height for it:

```css
#img { height: 200px; }
```